# Selenium Loop through table pages

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to scrape a table of contents with Selenium and Beautiful Soup, but I can't seem to find a good way to loop through the table's pages given how the HTML is written as there is no next button and the currently selected page button has the active class.
This is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

path_driver = "C:/Users/CS330584/Documents/Documentos de Defesa da Concorrência/Automatização de Processos/chromedriver.exe"
website = "https://sat.sef.sc.gov.br/tax.NET/Sat.Dva.Web/ConsultaPublicaDevedores.aspx"
value_search = "300"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver)
driver.get(website)

search_max = driver.find_element_by_id("Body_Main_Main_ctl00_txtTotalDevedores")
search_max.send_keys(value_search)

btn_consult = driver.find_element_by_id("Body_Main_Main_ctl00_btnBuscar")
btn_consult.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

i = 1
while True:
    try:
   #some wait
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView']/tbody/tr[51]/td/ul/li' and .='[]']".format(str(i + 1))).click()
    
    except:
        break
```

How can I effectively (or even not so effectively) loop through these table pages in order to scrape the data ?

Comment: at the bottom are buttons to next pages witch runs JavaScript code `javascript:GridView_ScrollToTop(&quot;Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView&quot;);__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Body$Main$Main$grpDevedores$gridView','Page$1')` and you could use it to change pages. You have to only update number in `Page$1'`

Comment: in your code you forgot `i = i + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Buttons to next pages run `JavaScript` code

```
javascript:GridView_ScrollToTop('Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView');__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Body$Main$Main$grpDevedores$gridView','Page$1')
```

and you can also use it to change pages.

You have to only update number in `Page$1` - ie. using `f-string`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import math

path_driver = "C:/Users/CS330584/Documents/Documentos de Defesa da Concorrência/Automatização de Processos/chromedriver.exe"
website = "https://sat.sef.sc.gov.br/tax.NET/Sat.Dva.Web/ConsultaPublicaDevedores.aspx"
value_search = 300

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(website)

search_max = driver.find_element_by_id("Body_Main_Main_ctl00_txtTotalDevedores")
search_max.send_keys(value_search)

btn_consult = driver.find_element_by_id("Body_Main_Main_ctl00_btnBuscar")
btn_consult.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)


pages = math.ceil(value_search/50)
print('pages:', pages)

for i in range(2, pages+1):
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script(f"javascript:GridView_ScrollToTop('Body_Main_Main_grpDevedores_gridView');__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Body$Main$Main$grpDevedores$gridView','Page${i}')")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

---

You can also get all links to page and use `i` as index - you have to add 1 to skip link `<<`

```
for i in range(2, pages+1):
    try:
        time.sleep(2)

        all_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="sat-gv-pagination-row"]//li//a')
        all_links[i+1].click()

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

Or you can use `f-string` to create xpath with `li[{i+1}]`

```
for i in range(2, pages+1):
    try:
        time.sleep(2)

        next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//tr[@class="sat-gv-pagination-row"]//li[{i+1}]//a')
        next_link.click()
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```